# writing file using php with var

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a php file that load data and save them to php file,
every things works fine except when I'm trying to write a var (as var) into the file
like:

```
$content="include 'pages/page1.html'; 
include 'pages/page2.html';";

$content.="$ChangingPage";
$content.="include 'pages/page3.html';;
```

I get error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: ChangingPage in /MYHOST/pages/write_properties.php on line 75

I want the new php file to contain the `ChangingPage` as `var ($)`

Comment: The error looks pretty self-explanatory. You haven't defined `$ChangingPage` anywhere in your code, as far as I can tell. Also, I have no idea what are you trying to do with the `$content` variable declaration in the first line.

Comment: As I understand it, they are trying to output text that happens to be code and doesn't want it to execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In php when you use quotes it will automatically use a variable when you use a dollar sign. It will also use the variable value when you use quotes and wrap the variable in { } brackets

To avoid this escape the dollar sign or switch to ' instead of "

```
$a = "text"; //text
$b = "$a"; //text
$c = "{$a}"; //text

$d = '$a'; //$a
$e = '{$a}'; //{$a}
$f = "\$a"; //$a
```

Comment: or escape the dollar sign... `" \$variablename "`

Comment: I tried it and it works, but now my new php doesn't run, the script is good I've missing ; or something like ;-)